# Data pipeline proposal

Tags: mysql, database, data-warehouse, database-backups

Our product has been growing steadily over the last few years and we are now on a turning point as far as data size for some of our tables is, where we expect that the growth of said tables will probably double or triple in the next few months, and even more so in the next few years. We are talking in the range of 1.4M now, so over 3M by the end of the summer and (since we expect growth to be exponential) we assume around 10M at the end of the year. (M being million, not mega/1000).

The table we are talking about is sort of a logging table. The application receives data files (csv/xls) on a daily basis and the data is transfered into said table. Then it is used in the application for a specific amount of time - a couple of weeks/months - after which it becomes rather redundant. That is: if all goes well. If there is some problem down the road, the data in the rows can be useful to inspect for problem solving.

What we would like to do is periodically clean up the table, removing any number of rows based on certain requirements, but instead of actually deleting the rows move them 'somewhere else'.
We currently use MySQL as a database and the 'somewhere else' could be the same, but can be anything. For other projects we have a Master/Slave setup where the whole database is involved, but that's not what we want or need here. It's just some tables where the Master table would need to become shorter and the Slave only bigger, not a one-on-one sync.

The main requirement for the secondary store would be that the data should be easy to inspect/query when need to, either by SQL or another DSL, or just visual tooling. So we are not interested in backing up the data to one or more CSV files or another plain text format, since that is not as easy to inspect. The logs will then be somewhere on S3 so we would need to download it, grep/sed/awk on it... We'd much rather have something database like that we can consult.

I hope the problem is clear?

For the record: while the solution can be anything we prefer to have the simplest solution possible. It's not that we don't want Apache Kafka (example), but then we'd have to learn it, install it, maintain it. Every new piece of technology adds onto our stack, the lighter it remains the more we like it ;).

Thanks!

PS: we are not just being lazy here, we have done some research but we just thought it'd be a good idea to get some more insight in the problem.

Comment: What's wrong with moving the historic data to another table? This seems to be a simple question with an obvious solution - or am I missing something?

Comment: Sry @NickW just noticed your answer now! Well, there is nothing wrong with that, it was our initial approach. We thought it was just too obvious and easy, but it might be a very good option. KISS, right?